# How can I validate image size and dimensions before uploading?

Tags: javascript

I'm wanting to add functionality to validate the size of an image before it's uploaded. Validation javascript exists to check other fields and the file type, and that seems to work. I tried plugging in some code to check the size and it doesn't work.

HTML

```
 <input type="file" name="pin" id="pin" value="">
```

javascript

```
function validateUpload()
{
description = $('textarea#blurb').val();
pin         = $('input#pin').val();
btitle      = $('input#btitle').val();
authname    = $('input#authname').val();


$('#error_description').html('');
$('#error_pin').html('');
$('#error_btitle').html('');
$('#error_authname').html('');

failed = 0 ;

if(description=="")
{
    $('#error_description').html('Please provide a description.');
    failed = 1;
}
if(btitle=="")
{
    $('#error_btitle').html('Please provide a title.');
    failed = 1;
}
if(authname=="")
{
    $('#error_authname').html('Please provide an author name.');
    failed = 1;
}
if(pin=="")
{
    $('#error_pin').html('Please upload a book cover.');
    failed = 1;
}
else{
    image = pin.toString().split(".");
    if((image[1]!='png')&&(image[1]!='jpg')&&(image[1]!='gif')&&(image[1]!='jpeg')&&(image[1]!='PNG')&&(image[1]!='GIF')&&(image[1]!='JPEG')&&(image[1]!='JPG'))
    {
        $('#error_pin').html('Invalid image.');
         failed = 1;
    }

}
$('#pin').bind('change', function() {
            if(this.files[0].size > 200000){
                $('#error_pin').html('File is too large.');
                failed = 1;
            }
        });





if(failed==1)
{
    return false;
}
else{
    return true;
}
```

Comment: This can only be done by modern browsers. see http://jsbin.com/oTAtIpA/3/edit  and http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/

Comment: Do it in PHP. Really. people could just disable JS and then upload the file and your file would be still too large, but uploaded.

Comment: I'd prefer checks on both client and serverside..

Comment: @bwoebi NO. there might be a limitation on the request size. check it on the client. vicious people might upload huge file to your server consume all memory....

Comment: @RoyiNamir The same vicious people have thhe possibility to disable the javascript. Not a solution.

Comment: @bwoebi the most important thing is to protect your server/app. if one does not negotiate with you regarding those terms , let him go.

Comment: I changed up my methodology and believe I solved it. 

I put some script outside the validateUpload code...



Basically it sets the value of a hidden field on the page... to 1, if it failed. The validateUpload was then simply modified to return the error, just as it would for other fields which failed validation. 

When they go back and re-upload the file, if it's the correct size it will reset the hidden field, and get rid of the error advisory.

Comment: Is there a good way to adapt similar code to check the height and width of the image as well?

Answer (score 0):

Can you change 'this'  to  : $('#pin')[0] and try

Change this :

```
 if(this.files[0].size > 200000){
            $('#error_pin').html('File is too large.');
            failed = 1;
 }
```

in to

```
if($('#pin')[0].files[0].size > 200000){
            $('#error_pin').html('File is too large.');
            failed = 1;
 }
```